# For XML Path - no arguments

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the SQL statement below:

```
SELECT TOP 1
       STUFF((SELECT ' ' + Name AS [text()]
                FROM dbo.Test 
               ORDER BY id
                 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' ) Concatenated
 FROM TEST
```

I do not understand why `XML PATH` has no arguments i.e. `''`. I have looked at the documentation but I cannot find an answer and hence the reason for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [MSDN documentation on PATH mode.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510462.aspx)

The value passed to PATH is the XML structure in which to place the XML you are generating.

You can do a static element such as :

```
SELECT TOP 1
      (SELECT ' ' + Name AS [text()]
                FROM (select 'a' as name, 1 as id) TEST
               ORDER BY id
                 FOR XML PATH('Root')) Concatenated
```

You can have a static nested element by using a ROOT mode as well:

```
SELECT TOP 1
      (SELECT ' ' + Name AS [text()]
                FROM (select 'a' as name, 1 as id) TEST
               ORDER BY id
                 FOR XML PATH('Child'), ROOT('Parent')) Concatenated
```

And then you can also build out XML Namespaces and queries in your source query and then use them in the final XML path like so

```
 select 
    id as "@id",
    name as "SomeChild/ModelName",
from TEST   
FOR XML PATH('Parent'), ROOT('Root')
```

In your case, you're setting the root element as '' (i.e. nothing) so it just spits out your concatenated text (and then you "STUFF" it to remove the leading space.)

Answer (score 0):

`FOR XML`

Gives results as `XML` instead of the default rowset.

There are multiple modes you can specify in a `FOR XML` clause, one of which is `PATH` as you have above.  In your example you are using an empty set as the row element name, specifying the element name is optional.

Observing the default behavior may help you understand the behavior when the row element name is set:

```
SELECT ' ' + Name AS [text()]
                FROM dbo.Test 
               ORDER BY id
                 FOR XML PATH
```

[FOR XML (SQL Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx)

[Examples: Using PATH Mode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510462.aspx)